# Flyway 3.2.1 info on OSX gives error 'Invalid version containing non-numeric characters'

Tags: mysql, macos, flyway

Context: OSX 10.10.3, java 1.8_51, downloaded flyway: flyway-commandline-3.2.1-macosx-x64.tar.gz, database in MySQL 5.5 server

Unzipped tar, entered directory and changed flyway.conf to proper URL, username and password.

Tested the username/password -> works

When I do `./flyway info` I get the following error:

`ERROR Invalid version containing non-numeric characters. Only 0..9 and . are allowed. Invalid version:`

A coworker has the same setup and she doesn't have this error, but the expected behaviour.

When I revert back to version flyway 3.1 it works as expected.

Any ideas what is wrong here?